# How to use Lambda in Excel to return array of results for an array

Tags: arrays, excel, lambda, xlookup, excel-lambda

I am becoming more and more familiar with Excel's new array functionality and absolutely love the direction it is all headed.

I've been trying to find a way to have a single formula which will spill an array of multiple columns, each which correspond to the proper SKU in column A.

In order to achieve this currently, I just write a formula like this, then I drop the formula down to the bottom of the data.

```
=XLOOKUP($A2,SKUP[SKU],HSTACK(SKUP[SKU Desc],SKUP[Package Desc],SKUP[Supplier]),"Not Found",0)
```

I just recently learned about `LAMBDA` formulas and trying to learn more about them. I was wondering if there is any way I could change this formula to reference all SKUs in column A, instead of having to use just 1 SKU at a time for this calculation?

I was thinking of something like this:

```
=LAMBDA(sku_array,LET(r,ROW(),s,INDEX(sku_array,r),XLOOKUP...
```

However, each attempt I've tested with something similar just seems to give errors. If I change the original `XLOOKUP` formula making the search value the whole column, it still only results 1 column.

Comment: `=XLOOKUP($A$2:$A$100,SKUP[SKU],HSTACK(SKUP[SKU Desc],SKUP[Package Desc],SKUP[Supplier]),"Not Found",0)`  No need for LAMBDA.

Comment: Hey @ScottCraner that doesn't work unfortunately, when you type it that way, it only results the first column (Just tested, only provides SKU Desc, does not include other columns)

Comment: Ah yes try this: `=MAKEARRAY(ROWS($A$2:$A$100),3,LAMBDA(x,y,XLOOKUP(INDEX($A$2:$A$100,x),SKUP[SKU],CHOOSE(y,SKUP[SKU],HSTACK(SKUP[SKU Desc],SKUP[Package Desc],SKUP[Supplier]),"Not Found",0)))`

Comment: Or you could HSTACK 3 XLOOKUPS: `=HSTACK(XLOOKUP($A$2:$A$100,SKUP[SKU],SKUP[SKU Desc],"Not Found",0),XLOOKUP($A$2:$A$100,SKUP[SKU],SKUP[Package Desc],"Not Found",0),XLOOKUP($A$2:$A$100,SKUP[SKU],SKUP[Supplier],"Not Found",0))`

Comment: Why not just `HSTACK` first then `FILTER` the result? `=FILTER(HSTACK(SKUP[SKU Desc],SKUP[Package Desc],SKUP[Supplier]),ISNUMBER(MATCH(SKUP[SKU],A2:A100,0)))`

Comment: @ScottCraner I'll have to look into your first recommendation, definitely something I'd love to learn the functionality of. Thanks for the tips

Comment: @JosWoolley I think your idea is going to be best, especially because within that HSTACK I could add other calculations if needed. Thanks for the tip, wish you would've posted an answer instead of a comment so I could mark it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `HSTACK` first then `FILTER` the result?

`=FILTER(HSTACK(SKUP[SKU Desc],SKUP[Package Desc],SKUP[Supplier]),ISNUMBER(MATCH(SKUP[SKU],A2:A100,0)))`